# Query labels with a specific attribute in ClearCase

Tags: version-control, clearcase

How can I query those of the labels in ClearCase with cleartool that have a specific attribute.

I can list the labels with

```
lstype -kind lbtype
```

but I'd like to get only those that have an attribute called TestAttr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can

- first find all the version with a certain attribute
- then describe those versions in order to display their respective branch

(unix syntax)

```
cleartool find . -version 'attype(an_attribute_name)' \
  -exec 'cleartool descr -fmt "%Sn" "$CLEARCASE_XPN" '
```

You will still need to parse the result to extract the branch, and `sort -u` the result.

---

The OP comments:

> I'd like to query the labels not the files. I have no files with that attribute

Then `find` is the wrong command.

The best you could do is to list all labels in a given VOB, and describe them in order to display their attribute (if they have one)

```
ct lstype -kind lbtype -invob vob:/avob -fmt "%n ~ %[an_attribute_name]a"
```

Only the lines with some value displayed after the "`~`" (an arbitrary separator just put here to easily distinguish the name of the label from its attribute value) are to be considered.
A label with no attribute (at least not the '`an_attribute_name`' attribute) will display only its name followed by "`~`", without any other data after the '`~`'.

Comment: I'd like to query the labels not the files. I have no files with that attribute.

Comment: @Vereb: refined my answer to display attribute on labels, not on files with labels.